# Monotone covergent sequence

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Let $c>0,a_1=c/2,a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(c+a_n^2)$. Determine $c$ for which the sequence converges, for each $c$, and find $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$.

I have the feeling that I should use induction but I don't know how to start.

Comment: This is (almost) identical with [another question up for bounty](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491221/discuss-the-convergence-of-left-a-n-right-where-a-n1-fraca-0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fixed point theorem here. This states that if an iteration

$a_{n+1} = f(a_{n})$

has a stationary point $a_{*}$ such that $a_{*} = f(a_{*})$ and $|f'(a_{*})| < 1$ holds then $a_{*}$ is a point of attraction.

To start with you need to find $a_{*}$ such that $a_{*} = \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}(c + a_{*}^2)$

and then find which values of $c$ allow for $|f'(a_{*})| < 1$

(Note that there may be several fixed points of the iteration)

Comment: we haven't learnt about fix point or iteration yet.

Comment: $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(c+a_n^2)$ defines an iteration for $a_{n+1}$. A point of convergence of the sequence $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots$ must have the property that it is a stationary point, i.e. that $a_{*} = 1/2(c+a_{*}^{2})$ otherwise the sequence is divergent. I hope that makes things more clear